# C# - Concatenate an in memory IList and IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, list, iqueryable

Suppose I have a List containing one string value. Suppose I also have an IQueryable that contains several strings from a database. I want to be able to concatenate these two containers into one list and then be able to call methods such as .Skip or .Take on the list. I want to be able to do this in such a way that when I combine the two containers I don't load all of the DB data into memory (only after I call .Skip and .Take). Basically, I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
IQueryable someQuery = myEntities.GetDBQuery(); // Gets "test2", "test3"
IList inMemoryList = new List();
inMemoryList.Add("test");

IList finalList = inMemoryList.Union(someQuery) // Can I do something like this without loading DB data into memory? finalList should contain all 3 strings.

// At this point it is fine to load the filtered query into memory.
foreach (string myString in finalList.Skip(100).Take(200))
{
   // Do work...
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see any issue doing this? Are you getting any error?

Comment: In the line where I create finalList, wouldn't all DB data be loaded into memory (not just the entries between .Skip(100).Take(200))?

Answer (score 2):

If I didn't misunderstand, you are trying to query the data, part of which comes from memory and others from database, like this:

```
//the following code will not compile, just for example
var dbQuery = BuildDbQuery();
var list = BuildListInMemory();
var myQuery = (dbQuery + list).OrderBy(aa).Skip(bb).Take(cc).Select(dd);
//and you don't want to load all records into memory by dbQuery 
//because you only need some of them
```

The short answer is **NO, you can't**. Consider the `.OrderBy` method, all data have to be in a same "place", otherwise the code can't sort them. So the code loads all records in database by `dbQuery` into memory(now they are in a same place) and then sorts all of them including those in `list`. That probably causes a memory issue when `dbQuery` gives thousands of rows.

**HOW TO RESOLVE**

1. Pass the data in `list` into database (as parameters of `dbQuery`) so that the query happens in database. This is easy if your `list` has only a few items.
2. If `list` also has lots of records that will makes `dbQuery` too complex, you can try to query twice, one for `dbQuery` and one for `list`. For example, you have 10,000 users in database and 1,000 users in your memory list, and you want to get the top 10 youngest users. You don't need to load 10,000 users into memory and then find the youngest 10. Instead, you find 10 youngest (ResultA) in `dbQuery` and load into memory, and 10 youngest (ResultB) in memory list, and then compare between ResultA and ResultB.

Comment: Can you give an example of #1 above? Actually, the in memory list only contains one element right now in my application (and it is not a string but an entity object) but I was trying to keep the question more generic so that it may help someone else in the future. Does that make it any easier?

Comment: @Andrew if your `list` has only one element, why not just query by `dbQuery` directly? Why do you want to query `dbQuery + 1` elements?

Answer (score 0):

I entirely agree with Danny's answer when he says you need to somehow find a way to include in memory user list into db so that you achieve what you want. As for the example which you sought in your comment, without knowing data structure of your User object, seems difficult. However assuming you would be able to connect the dots. Here is my suggested approach:

1. Create temporary table with identical structure that of your regular user table in your db and insert all your inmemory users into it
2. Write a query to Union temporary and regular table both identical in structure so that should be easy.
3. Return the result in your application and use it performing standard Linq operations
   If you want exact code which you can use as it is then you will have to provide your User object structure - fields type etc in db to enable me to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

You specify that your query and your list are both sequences of strings. someQuery can be performed completely on the database side (not in-memory)

Let's make your sequences less generic:

```
IQueryable<string> someQuery = ...
IList<string> myList = ...
```

You also specify that myList contains only one element.

```
string myOneAndOnlyString = myList.Single();
```

As your list is in-memory, this has to be performed in-memory. But because the list has only one element, this won't take any time.

The query that you request:

```
IQueryable<string> correctQuery = someQuery
    .Where(item => item.Equals(myOneandOnlyString)
    .Skip(skipCount)
    .Take(takeCount)
```

Use your SQL server profiler to check the used SQL and see that the request is completely performed in one SQL statement.